# Downloading a video as a best quality mp4 without audio?

Tags: audio, video, youtube, youtube-dl

I'm trying to download videos from Youtube as their best quality mp4, without the audio.

I know I can use youtube-dl -F to see all available formats, choose one and then run another command, but I want to download videos automatically through a script.

```
youtube-dl -f mp4 <URL>
```

This chooses the best mp4 option, but the one which also has audio, and so usually isn't the best video quality (720p instead of 1080p).

It seems like using bestvideo and then specifying the output path with an mp4 extension works:

```
youtube-dl -f bestvideo -o "%(title)s.mp4" <URL>
```

This is my current solution. Looking at the download options with -F, it seems like it still downloads the best video (regardless of it being an mp4 or not, in my case a webm), and then converts it to mp4? As the file sizes match between the downloaded file and the best quality in -F.

If anyone knows a better solution, please let me know! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify `mp4` as the format, youtube-dl *always* interprets this as requesting one of the "old" combined audio+video formats, which used to be the only option in the past.

To ask for one of the new audio-only or video-only streams used by DASH (which are the ones used for higher-quality streams), use `bestvideo` together with a `[filter]` which requests a specific codec:

- To request H.264 (AVC) specifically (i.e. check that `vcodec` starts with `avc1.`):

  ```
  youtube-dl -f "bestvideo[vcodec^=avc1.][ext=mp4]" <url>
  ```
- To request H.264 (AVC) or H.265 (HEVC) or whatever else happens to fit in an MP4 file:

  ```
  youtube-dl -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]" <url>
  ```

(Keep in mind that the same ".mp4" file format can have several different codecs! It won't contain VP8 or VP9 – those only come in MKV/WebM – but it *can* have either AVC or HEVC. While YouTube probably won't serve you HEVC, other video hosting sites occassionally will.)

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!